# Is it possible to make an object in kotlin OPEN?

Tags: object, kotlin, mockito

Is there a workaround to make this possible in Kotlin?

```
open object ClientFetcherHelper
```

I would like to be able to mock the object in java test class using Mockito.
I now there are multiple ways of mocking final classes or static methods, but I do not want to add more external library dependencies to a big project.

Or how could I mock the methods inside an object ?

Comment: You can't make it open, but you could create an interface that it adheres to and use that for your test.

Comment: @Tenfour04 But is it good practice to create this interface just for testing purposes?